# CSS minification using require js optimizer

Tags: css, backbone.js, requirejs

We have web application based on Backbone and Require JS. Currrently we uses Require Js optimizer to optimize the code.

It works well for js files.  I could see some css minification steps in Require JS documentation, but it does not work

Is there any way to do it? Consider i have 10 css files.

Answer (score 0):

I use grunt's [build tool](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt) and then there are a bunch of tasks you can load including [grunt-contrib](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib) which has both the tasks you need **requirejs** and **mincss**. Use this to load grunt-contrib within your grunt file.

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib');
```

Comment: Thanks. But i really want is to add minification support using require js optimizer, not using some other external tool.

Comment: I found it in the https://github.com/NilsLattek/backbone-requirejs-node-boilerplate